# Angular ngIf 2 attributes are true add a class condition

Tags: angular

On my html component I need to check if 2 attribute are equal to true and if they are I need to add a class.

Something like this:

```
<button
 [attr.one]="..."
 [attr.two]="..."
*ngIf="[attr.one] AND [attr.two] ... if both are true add a class to this button"></button>
```

Is to above possible to do in Angular 11+?

If so how?

Comment: You should check for the two functions evaluating if one or two should exist, example [attr.one]="shouldAddOne()"  [attr.one]="shouldAddTwo()" then the if would be *ngIf="shouldAddOne() && shouldAddTwo()"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume attribute one and two are binded variables, if thats the case then try using `NgClass` instead of `Ngif` here. Here is a very good article on how to use it https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-classes-with-ngclass-and-ngstyle.

```
[ngClass]="{'your_class': att1 && att2}" //att1 and att2 are binded variables
```

Answer (score 1):

i thing you need to use ngClass because ng If is used to hide or show entire element.
syntax of ngClass is below:

```
[ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp"
```

Example :

```
[ngClass]="{'my_class': step === 'step1'}"  // OR 
[ngClass]="step == 'step1' ? 'my_class1' : 'my_class2'"
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply class dynamically, Angular provide ngClass directive.

Here attributeOne and attributeTwo are the name of attribute.
varOne and varTwo are variables, its value assigned in component.ts file.

in component.html

```
<button [attr.attributeOne]="varOne" [attr.attributeTwo]="varTwo" [ngClass]="{'bgcolor': varOne && varTwo}"> Save </button>
```

in component.ts

```
 varOne: boolean = true;
 varTwo: boolean = true;
```

in component.css

```
.bgcolor{
  background-color: pink;
}
```

**Note:** Make sure you will not give attribute name that start with "**on**" like [attr.one]="...".
It will throw error.

For more information regarding ngClass and ngStyle you can refer [this](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/)